# Vuforia doesn't recognize triggers and shows watermark on iOS

Tags: vuforia

I have a project with image targets (triggers loaded from database). It works fine in Unity Editor (with webcam), but when I build it to iOS it opens with watermark and doesn't recognize triggers.
Unity 2020.3.25, Vuforia 10.14.4.
I've been using Vuforia for a long time and I have never had problems like this. Is this something related to Vuforia version?

I created simple project with image target and cube inside it. I tested basic license and cloud license. In both cases there is watermark when I build it to iOS and Vuforia doesn't recognize triggers.

Comment: I would first recommend that you upgrade your version of Unity Editor to 2021.3.0+ as recommended [here](https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/supported-versions) for Vuforia Engine 10.14. This may resolve the fact that recognition (triggers) is not working on device.

Comment: Tested on Unity 2022LTS and 2023, still not working on iOS

Comment: I just faced the same I am using Vuforia version 10.16.5 on Unity 2022.3.7f1, also happen when working with Unity 2022.3.5f1. Tested on android physical device. I updated from and older Vuforia 10.10 version.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I confirm that the solution in the comment will solve the issue. Apparently Vuforia does not support Unity 2020 anymore and the minimum version is now 2021.3.0+

Comment: No, it's not solved yet. I tried Unity 2022LTS or Unity 2023, both has watermark on iOS build. And even the basic marker tracking doesn't work. What's your tested version?
This is obviously a bug, if there is only one or two specific versions of Unity support.

Comment: I used the latest 2021.3 version, that is currently 2021.3.28f

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out again with older version. Sadly that Vuforia haven't fixed this problem. Unity 2021 LTS is a bit outdated now, while Unity 2023 has been already released already.

Comment: I've done further testings, and realised that this bug will be triggered when I upgrade my Vuforia SDK from older version. It works fine if I create a new Unity project with either Unity 2021 or Unity 2023.