# Vuforia Unity issue with Basic License

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am developing an imgae target based AR application using Vuforia Engine in Unity 3d. I had setup the API key properly in vuforia configuration file. In Editor Vuforia is working fine but in Android build,App shows Vuforia Watermark and Image database is not loded. Please let me know how o fix this.

Try Changing the Vuforia Key as well as accounts.

Comment: This is reported in the following post [Vuforia doesn't recognize triggers and shows watermark on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76058877/vuforia-doesnt-recognize-triggers-and-shows-watermark-on-ios)